# Looking for sympathetic language

Tags: paraphrasing

We have a survey.

> If you get a chance, go ahead and take the survey by phone or online, so that my store knows how I am doing, my name is Jack and the contact information of my store can be found on the bottom of your receipt.
>   Have a nice day!

What are some best paraphrased version of this piece of speech in order to promote a sense of sympathy?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to generate cooperation is to show someone how it would help them. In this case I would tell the survey taker (customer) how it might benefit them.

"We are conducting a survey in order to better serve our customers. If you have a free moment, please take this survey either online or by phone.  Your feedback will allow both me (Jack) and my store (listed at the bottom of the receipt) to do a better job of serving you in the future."